# Discord.js - Any way to trigger an event when somebody recieves a specific role?

Tags: discord, discord.js

sorry in advance; I'm new to Javascript and Discord.js. What I basically want to do is check when a user receives a specific role, and then send them a message. I feel like it shouldn't be as hard as it is, but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`GuildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event, which emits when:

> a guild member changes - i.e. new role, removed role, nickname. Also emitted when the user's details (e.g. username) change.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

  // if the member gained the role
  if (!oldMember.roles.cache.has('<Role ID>') && 
  newMember.roles.cache.has('<Role ID>')) {

    // do something....

  };
})
```